# Как выполнять действие каждый час?

Tags: php

Нужно что бы каждый час выполнялось действие

````
$db = getDB();
            $x = 0;
            foreach ($db['dl_cum'] as $cumID => $cum) {
                if (($cum['time_created']+3600) < time()) {
                    unset($db['dl_cum'][$cumID]);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            file_put_contents('3.db', json_encode($db));```
````

Подскажите как можно реализовать?

Comment: можно воспользоватся стандартной утилитой `cron`

Comment: Здесь скорее вопрос - каждый час? или один раз по истечению часа после какого-то события. В первом случае - cron, во втором лучше смотреть в сторону очередей

Comment: каждый час что бы

Comment: как можно сделать не используя cron?

Comment: cron или очередь событий вам в помощь

Comment: А чем вам cron не угодил?

Comment: ранее не был знаком с ним

Comment: есть еще команда [`at`](https://linux-faq.ru/page/komanda-at)

Comment: Тогда самое время познакомиться с cron. Пригодится в работе